# The default title of reactpy is 'Reactpy', how to customize the title for reactpy

Tags: python

The default title of reactpy is 'Reactpy', how to set the title for reactpy, when I set html.title('') it didn't take effect.

```py
@component
def App():
    temps_list = read_last10('pi_temp.txt')
    return html._(
        html.title("raspberry pi temperature monitor"),
        html.h1("raspberry"),
        html.img({
            "src": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/27/21/42/stock-1863880_1280.jpg",
            "style": {"width": "10%", "margin_left": "0%"},
            }),
        DataList(temps_list),
        html.p('cpu load: {}'.format(load_avg)),
        html.p('uptime: {}'.format(GetTime())),
    )
```

I tried to check the documentation on the official website but I don't quite understand it.
https://reactpy.dev/docs/index.html

Comment: Could you include `reactpy`'s documentation url?

Comment: yes, this is offical document
https://reactpy.dev/docs/index.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with `reactpy` but instead of directly adding `html.title` place it like this;  `html.head(html.title("raspberry pi"))`.

Answer (score 0):

I poked around a little and this is what I found out:

If you are using the run() function to use the Reactpy backend to test the application, the title and icon of the page are referenced here:

```
reactpy.backend._common.CommonOptions
```

While you can change these Options by editing the code at this point to change the name, it will only be applied to the page if you run it in the testing backend of Reactpy and only within your current environment. I don't think this is very useful or advisable.

My suggestion would be to add this code:

```
html.head(
    html.title('raspberry pi temperature monitor')
),
```

to the return statement and then run the page outside of the backend testing and see if this works.